# How can I create something like Template,enum of my own?

Tags: c++

In C++ we can create Template as follow

```
  template<typename T>
```

In C++ we can create enum as follow

```
enum color {red ,green, yellow}
```

So now what I want is I want to create my own template as below.

```
   template<typename T>
   // myTemaple // this is just example
   void max(T x)
   {return x;}
```

So now what I want is I want to create my enum template as below.

```
myenum color {red,color} // this is just example
```

Comment: Of course you can declare template classes / enums on your own! That's what it's all about programming in c++ (among other techniques)! Get a book about the basics,

Comment: @g-makulik I think my question is not clear. Let me eloborate it . What I want is in C++ we can create template function, class now I want to create my own template ? I don't want to use template provided by C++. Is it clear ?

Comment: why negative points what is wrong with the question ?

Comment: 1. Edit your question to provide this information. 2. No you usually can't 'override' STL provided classes with your own implementations, but you can provide your own implementations to provide e.g. `std::ostream`, `std::istream` interfaces.

Comment: @g-makulik not clear can you give me some example.

Comment: Same for me, NOT CLEAR! Can you give an example in your question what you want to achieve, best with source code you have tried?

Comment: @chris and g-makulik I have edited the original question. Please and let me know if it is still not clear. I hope this time it's clear :(

Comment: +1 for editing, but sorry it's still unclear: Do you want to extend an already declared `enum color;` with your own values, or accept a template class declaration both of these for instantiations with `T`?

Comment: @g-makulik no I don't want to use enum at all. I want to define my own defination of enum(say name would be myenum) who works same like enum, but I don't want to use system provided enum. Clear?

Comment: What exactly do you think is _'system provided'_ enum?? _'who works same like enum'_ For my understanding enum's don't have a heavy behavioral model besides simple operations on their bare value definitions (e.g. operations like operator==() or operator<=()) which are intrinsic already. Which behaviors do you want to change with your own _'enum'_ implemtation??

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if you're even on the right track about understanding c++ enums and their use with templates, or whatever you're asking for ...

Comment: @g-makulik it's simple think of as there is no enum(suppose) in C++ and now you want to define your own enum. Again there is no enum(suppose)

Comment: And what should be provided instead? Certain constant values??

Comment: yes constant values should be provided.  e:g                             myenum{green,red,yellow} ;                                                         cout << red << endl; // should print 1 as output

Comment: OK, did you try s.th. like `struct myenum { static const int green = 0; static const int red = 1; static const int yellow = 2; }` (sorry cannot post a properly formatted answer, as your question's still 'on hold')? But I can't see any benefit you would achieve over a regular `enum` definition. Elaborate please (Edit question!!) ...

Comment: yes now you got it. So is there any way for template ? I salute your patience.

Comment: What should be the benefit?? Introducing `T` instead of `int`? I don't get it!! If you want to have enums to be bound to underlying types, see [tag:c++11]'s provisions for declaration of [class based enums](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
enum color : int {
    red = 1 ,
    yellow = 0 ,
    green = 2 ,
};
```

No template needed.